# TFS Unit Testing using unmanaged DLLs

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, unmanaged

We need to test a .NET application that references a .NET Wrapper DLL that references unmanaged C++ DLL.

The TFS Unit Testing project only copies the .NET Wrapper DLL and not the last one abd tests fail.

How can I tell to MSTest to copy all the necessary files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add all the necessary files/DLL to the Deployment section of the Local.testsettings file and to add the */testsettings:Local.testsettings* parameter to the MSTest command line list of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It cannot. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856278/why-the-native-dll-is-not-copied-to-the-output-directory).

Instead the best short term solution is to use a post-build event.

The managed and unmanaged dlls can be merged into one single dll file with some hazzle. For example SQLite achieves this.